# How to customize QToolButtons from QToolBar in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar, qtoolbutton

I am having QToolBar with various tool buttons on it. I want to customize those buttons with some simple effects like, it should be seen that button is pressed,  after pressing it should change its icon color or background color etc.
I tried but I could not succeed.

```
_toolbar = new QToolBar;
_toolbar->setIconSize(QSize(35,35));
_toolbar->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);        
   
void createIcons()
{
    _zoomInIcon = QIcon::fromTheme("zoom-in");
    _zoomIn = new QAction(_zoomInIcon, "Zoom in", this);      
   // code for other icons    
   
   _toolbar->addAction(_zoomIn);
}
      
    
void myClass::ZoomIn()
{
    _zoomIn->setCheckable(true);
    //QToolButton:_zoomInIcon {background-color: red; }
    //setStyleSheet('background-color: red;');
   // other logic  
}
```

Moreover I am using Qt's default icons from this [default-icons](https://gist.github.com/peteristhegreat/c0ca6e1a57e5d4b9cd0bb1d7b3be1d6a)
But some of the icons are not looking good specially `save in` and `save in as`.
So does any one knows more default icons apart from above link in Qt ?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below (not tested)

```
//Get the tool button using the action
QToolButton* zoomInButton = mytoolbar->widgetForAction(_zoomIn);

//Set the style you want.
zoomInButton->setStyleSheet("QToolButton:pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : red;"
                             "}"
                             );
```

And you can use all `QPushButton` styles, if your tool button don't have a menu.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbutton

> The QToolButton has no menu. In this case, the QToolButton is styled
> exactly like QPushButton.